# whether to adjust or not adjust for baseline in longitudinal RCT

Tags: r, mixed-model, stata, adjustment

I have a longitudinal RCT data, aiming to compare the superiority of one group with high exercising to the other group with low exercising to see the improving of pain (pain is outcome). Data is collected at baseline, 3 months and 6 months. So now I am in doubt about the modeling. I use linear mixed model, but: which of mixed linear model in correct? why?

Comment: First let's start with the research question.  What is the question you're hoping the RCT will answer?  I understand its about superiority, but just tell me in plain language.  Is it about a single point in time, or about evolution of the pain score in time?

Comment: @Demetri Pananos it is about the evolution of the pain score in time.

Comment: Always adjust for baseline and often allow baseline to be nonlinear.  See Chapter 7 of hbiostat.org/rmsc for detailed reasoning.

Comment: @FrankHarrell Thank you for your response. Could you please elaborate on "often allow baseline to be non-linear"? for the case of longitudinal RCT, e.g, baseline, fup1 and fup2. If I adjust for baseline as covariate, then dose that mean to include also baseline in dependent variable or only include fup1 and fup2 as dependent variable?

Comment: The follow-up response measurements appear as raw data that ignore baseline.  The baseline is often modeled as linearly predicting the follow-up responses, but since the baseline is the dominant predictor of follow-up you want to make sure to model baseline so as to remove the chance of lack of fit.  When the sample size is not very small I allow baseline to nonlinearly predict follow-up because I’ve seen nonlinear relationships too often (HAM-D depression scale, KCCQ quality of life in heart failure studies).  Patients with large baselines can sometime have quick major benefit of a drug.

Comment: You might find this paper relevant: https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S030438781200003X?via%3Dihub

Answer (score 2):

I don't think the baseline should be explicitly modelled.  If the treatment is randomly allocated, then groups are exchangeable, and their mean difference is 0.  Rather, it would be a good idea to adjust for baseline to increase precision in your estimate of the treatment effect.

Hence, I would fit a model that looks like

```
lmer(y ~ baseline_y + factor(time) * group + (1 | id))
```

- Adjusting for baseline pain a la ANCOVA should increase precision by reducing residual variance.  This assumes that baseline and pain scores are highly correlated.
- Treating time as a factor allows for non-linear evolution of the treatment effect.  I think treating it as such is worth the spent degree of freedom.

Comment: @user358238 y is whatever your outcome is.  I'm not sure what those equations in your question are trying to convey.  If they are R formulae, I've never seen the parens used in an outcome.  The lmer call I've shown is what I would fit assuming the data you collect are in tidy format (one row per subject per time point)

Comment: In a mixed model, you do not need to add the baseline outcome measurement as a covariate. Actually, by doing so, you assume that all other measurements have the same correlation with the baseline one. The random intercepts term explicitly specifies that subjects start at different levels at baseline (i.e., time zero). Your call to `lmer()` does not seem to include random effects.

Comment: @DimitrisRizopoulos good point (the lack of random intercept is a typo). It would be better to adjust for non-baseline clinical covars which would have the same effect - namely variance reduction - without the issues you describe. Though, the random effect may reduce residual variation sufficiently in and of itself.  If you like, feel free to edit the answer and I’ll accept as I’m currently away from my desk.

Comment: @DimitrisRizopoulos, any chance you could turn your comment into a longer answer? I'm really interested to read more about this. Thanks!